# Where do I extract cursor theme in Debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian

Can someone tell me where I can copy the cursor theme downloaded from Gnome-Look in Debian 8? I have extracted it to `/etc/X11/cursors` and changed its attributes to 755 but when I want to change it in Tweak Tool, I can't see it on the list.

Any advice?

Comment: What did you download? What's the folder structure you get from whatever you downloaded?

Comment: In the extracted folder I have: cursor.theme , index.theme and cursors folder.

Comment: Try copying the entire directory to `/usr/share/icons`, which is where cursor themes like [DMZ](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/dmz-cursor-theme/filelist) seems to keep their files.

Comment: Thank You so much ! It worked, if not you, I would probably stuck for next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages of cursor themes like [DMZ](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/dmz-cursor-theme/filelist) keep their files in `/usr/share/icons`. So, for a system-wide installation of the cursor theme, that seems to be the correct location.